# Round Half Down in Swift

Tags: swift, rounding

Is there a rounding mode in Swift that behaves same as [ROUND_HALF_DOWN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) in Java?

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round down. Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is > 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN.

Example:

- 2.5 rounds down to 2.0
- 2.6 rounds up to 3.0
- 2.4 rounds down to 2.0

For a negative number:

- -2.5 rounds up to -2.0
- -2.6 rounds down to -3.0
- -2.4 rounds up to -2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is – as far as I can tell – no `FloatingPointRoundingRule` with the same behavior as Java's `ROUND_HALF_DOWN`, but you can get the result with a combination of `rounded()` and `nextDown` or `nextUp`:

```
func roundHalfDown(_ x: Double) -> Double {
    if x >= 0 {
        return x.nextDown.rounded()
    } else {
        return x.nextUp.rounded()
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
print(roundHalfDown(2.4)) // 2.0
print(roundHalfDown(2.5)) // 2.0
print(roundHalfDown(2.6)) // 3.0

print(roundHalfDown(-2.4)) // -2.0
print(roundHalfDown(-2.5)) // -2.0
print(roundHalfDown(-2.6)) // -3.0
```

Or as a generic extension method, so that it can be used with all floating point types (`Float`, `Double`, `CGFloat`):

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    func roundedHalfDown() -> Self {
        return self >= 0 ? nextDown.rounded() : nextUp.rounded()
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
print((2.4).roundedHalfDown()) // 2.0
print((2.5).roundedHalfDown()) // 2.0
print((2.6).roundedHalfDown()) // 3.0

print((-2.4).roundedHalfDown()) // -2.0
print((-2.5).roundedHalfDown()) // -2.0
print((-2.6).roundedHalfDown()) // -3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift implements `.round()` function with rules, According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/2298113-round)

### FloatingPointRoundingRule

```
case awayFromZero
```

Round to the closest allowed value whose magnitude is greater than or equal to that of the source.

```
case down
```

Round to the closest allowed value that is less than or equal to the source.

```
case toNearestOrAwayFromZero
```

Round to the closest allowed value; if two values are equally close, the one with greater magnitude is chosen.

```
case toNearestOrEven
```

Round to the closest allowed value; if two values are equally close, the even one is chosen.

```
case towardZero
```

Round to the closest allowed value whose magnitude is less than or equal to that of the source.

```
case up
```

Round to the closest allowed value that is greater than or equal to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do the similar things using NSNumberFormatter and RoundingMode

Read them here

[NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

[RoundingMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/roundingmode)

Answer (score 0):

As @MohmmadS said those are built in methods for rounding.

You can implement custom rounding like this:

```
func round(_ value: Double, toNearest: Double) -> Double {
    return round(value / toNearest) * toNearest
}

func roundDown(_ value: Double, toNearest: Double) -> Double {
    return floor(value / toNearest) * toNearest
}

func roundUp(_ value: Double, toNearest: Double) -> Double {
    return ceil(value / toNearest) * toNearest
}
```

Example:

```
round(52.376, toNearest: 0.01) // 52.38
round(52.376, toNearest: 0.1)  // 52.4
round(52.376, toNearest: 0.25) // 52.5
round(52.376, toNearest: 0.5)  // 52.5
round(52.376, toNearest: 1)    // 52
```

Comment: i think the question is  "is there a rounding mode in Swift" , not how to implement

Comment: @MohmmadS you are right but maybe he is looking for a solution !

Answer (score 0):

```
 var a = 6.54
        a.round(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
        // a == 7.0

        var b = 6.54
        b.round(.towardZero)
        // b == 6.0


        var c = 6.54
        c.round(.up)
        // c == 7.0


        var d = 6.54
        d.round(.down)
        // d == 6.0
```

You can do like this as well but need to take values after decimal as well.